# Associative array values showing as strings instead of int

Tags: php, arrays

I apologize if this was answered, I did look for a bit but couldn't find anything.

I need to add the same values from two different arrays. I have...

```
$monData = array([mjones] => 50,[total] => 50)
$tueData = array([mjones] => 50,[total] => 50)
```

I need to put the sum of the [total]'s in to an email, but when I do

```
<html>'.$monData['total] + $tueData['total].'</html>
```

I get an error about a non-numeric value. I'm sure this is easy and I'm overlooking something stupid, but I couldn't find anything to answer it without rebuilding the entire arrays which would take a lot of work.

Edit:

Sorry about the syntax errors. The error isn't the arrays it was just summing the values of them. I can see why it was misleading though, I apologize.

Comment: I can tell you it has nothing to do with the difference between `50` and `'50'`,  PHP doesn't care about those things.  `I get an error about a non-numeric value` Why not post the full error

Comment: First you should fix all those syntax errors. If your next question is "what syntax errors?" then you also need to turn `error_reporting` on.

Comment: This is not my exact code, I quickly retyped it to give an idea, and it seems to have changed the location of some commas. But I will check it out, thanks.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix that is pretty much the full error. The only other part it mentions is the file name and the line number. Thanks for your comments in the other answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is due to [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), the `.` and `+` operators have equal precedence and so your expression is being interpreted as this:

```
(('<html>' . $monData['total']) + $tueData['total']) . '</html>'
```

The first operation yields a string, which you are then trying to add to a number with `+`, which gives you a non-numeric value error. With your specific values, it's like trying to add `'<html>50' + 50`.

You need to rewrite your code as

```
<html>'.($monData['total'] + $tueData['total']).'</html>
```

Comment: I was just gonna say there are some syntax errors in the original (probably just from creating the question) but now they are gone (in the answer at least)...   The only thing I would add is that its like `'<html>50' + 50` because of the op order.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I've corrected OPs syntax errors (I didn't notice them until SO formatted my answer). I've assumed they were copying errors. Either way, the rewrite code should give the correct result.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I upvoted your comment... I agree with it completely. I've included your suggested note in an edit.

Comment: Kool, Id upvote the answer again if I could ... Cheers!

Comment: Thanks guys. This isn't a copy, I just typed it up. Precedence fixed it though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<html>'.(intVal($monData['total]) + intVal($tueData['total])).'</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct code:

```
$monData = array('mjones' => 50, 'total' => 50);
$tueData = array('mjones' => 50, 'total' => 50);
```

Then in html:

```
<html><?php echo ($monData['total'] + $tueData['total']); ?></html>
```

or:

```
<?php echo '<html>'. ($monData['total'] + $tueData['total']) . '</html>'; ?>
```